# How can I get b6paper instead of a default letterpaper using the geometry package?

Tags: memoir, geometry, paper-size

I'm working on a `memoir` that I need to have a B6 paper size, but everytime I compile with `latexmk` it generates a PDF preview with a letter sized paper.  Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[b6paper]{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=4.9in, paperheight=6.9in}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I'm able to get the text block within the set limits, though.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When I run `latexmk` on your sample document and then view the resulting pdf with any of the PDF viewers, they all tell me (see the properties of the document) that the document is `B6`. If your problem persists, please provide more information on your environment, like PDF viewer and, in particular, any options handed to `latexmk`. Side-note: Remove the line `\geometry{paperwidth=4.9in, paperheight=6.9in}`, as the `b6paper` option does this anyway.

Comment: @gernot My current latexmkrc content is like the following: [.latexmkrc](https://pastebin.com/Z0t9Vh64)

Comment: With the settings in your config file, I still get the correct format. Is there any systemwide config file overriding your personal settings (which would be quite unusual)? What does evince tell you in the properties tab? Mine says `prc3 Envelope, Portrait (125 x 176mm)` which is the same as B6.

Comment: @gernot Thanks for your input, I was able to get the `prc3 Envelope` from the properties tab with @Mico's suggestion.  I eliminated the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memoir` document class provides lots of options for selecting the page size. E.g.,

```
\documentclass[b6paper]{memoir}
```

That'll give you a page that's 176 mm tall and 125 mm wide. (Running `\geometry{paperwidth=4.9in, paperheight=6.9in}` does *not* give the  correct dimensions. Rather, it gives you dimensions that are too small, by a fraction of a millimeter. I can see no reason for not using the exact size.)